How to show/hide sidebar in Files 46.2 (aka Nautilus)?
I have recently installed Ubuntu 24.04, and found that the default view in file manager Files (version 46.2, previously known as Nautilus) includes the sidebar.

I have found no way to hide the sidebar. The keyboard shortcut F9 is supposed to “Show/Hide Sidebar” but does not work for me.

Is this a possible bug in Files version 46.2? Is there any other way to (temporary) hide the sidebar?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/2059871

Unfortunatelly, since the transition from GTK3 to GTK4, the sidebar cannot manually be hidden anymore. It will disappear automatically if the windows size is below a certain threshold, but control is taken away from the user currently.
The issue was filed with Gnome but was closed because someone said "there is no need to hide it in large windows".

Thanks for pointing me to the discussion on gnome.org, which I have now read up on! IMO it is evidence of a poor decision making process that this decision was based on assumptions about the user experience and clear feedback (to restore the previous option to actively show and hide the sidebar) by multiple users was ignored.

If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the answer.

Your answer has not resolved my question "How to show/hide sidebar in Files 46.2 (aka Nautilus)?" (and possibly it will not be answered), but I appreciate your reply.

Answers that are disappointing are not necessarily wrong. In this case, developers removed the option to hide it. That is the sad truth, and that is thus unfortunately the correct answer to your question. It will only be fair to accept this answer. It is not because you do not like the outcome that the answer is not correct.
